# AutoHotkey - Shouldn't there be a difference between "return" and "break"?

Tags: function, loops, return, autohotkey, break

In the following script I'm using "return" and "break" in a loop but both have the same effect. What they do, is break the loop and continue with the rest of the script. However, after a return, the script shouldn't continue, I mean, that's what the break command is for, right? Breaking the loop and continuing with the script. After a return the script shouldn't continue  :?:

Here the script that does work:

```
F1 & i::
        start := A_TickCount
        Loop {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, G:\Saves\AutoHotkey - Snipping Tool - Screenshots\Chrome - New Tab.png
            totalTime := stop - start
            stop := A_TickCount
            if ErrorLevel = 0
                {
                break
                }
            else if totalTime > 3000
                {
                MsgBox, Something went wrong!
                return
                }
        } 
                msgbox, This message box should only appear when the immage was found!
                return
```

And here I made a function of the previous script and the "return" after "Something went wrong!" is interpreted as a "break" command it seems because after the msgbox dialog "Something went wrong!" I get the next msgbox.

```
F1 & i::
ImageSearchFunction("G:\Saves\AutoHotkey - Snipping Tool - Screenshots\Chrome - New Tab.png")
msgbox, This message box should only appear when the immage was found!
return
```

Here the function itself:

```
ImageSearchFunction(ImagePath){
        start := A_TickCount
        Loop {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %ImagePath%
            totalTime := stop - start
            stop := A_TickCount
            if ErrorLevel = 0
                {
                break
                }
            else if totalTime > 3000
                {
                MsgBox, Something went wrong!
                return
                }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on AutoHotkey. I have to use "exit" instead of "return" in the loop. That does the trick!